# Xamarin Forms linked DLL exception

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having an issue trying to link a DLL file into my Xamarin Forms project. I followed a suggestion [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/11951/#Comment_11951) to add the DLL file as a reference to the Android section of the project. I have also tried adding a reference link to the C# file accompanying the DLL file. I'm not
really sure what this exception is, particularly how to resolve it. Any help would be appreciated thanks. FYI the code below was only used in the MainActivity.cs file of the Android project, not the normal Xamarin.Forms files. But I was getting the same error there.

**Code used**:

```
UInt32 ftdiDeviceCount = 0;
var newDevice = new FTDI(); 
FTDI.FT_STATUS ftStatus = newDevice.GetNumberOfDevices(ref ftdiDeviceCount);
```

**Exception**:

`**System.EntryPointNotFoundException:** 'LoadLibrary assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)'`

Comment: you cannot just use any arbitrary DLL with a Xamarin project.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how to make this work?

Comment: No, because you have not explained exactly what it is you are trying to do,

Comment: I've tried to integrate a DLL file generated from a  Android Java binding into a Xamarin project. I am also actually just trying now to use this https://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/Essy.FTDIWrapper wrapper in my project, but not getting a whole lot of success here. I would like to be able to use FTDI with a Xamarin Forms project. Initially this project is intended for just Android, but we want it to be possible to extend it to a IOS platform as well. If you have any insight into how to integrate some form of FTDI wrapper into a Xamarin project that would be great, thanks @Jason.

Comment: generally speaking, if it's a .NET Standard library you should be able to use it in a Xamarin project

Comment: Ok, thats good to know thanks. So when using the FTDI recommended wrapper: https://www.nuget.org/packages/FTD2XX.Net/1.0.14?_src=template. I get this error: `NU1202 Package FTD2XX.Net 1.0.14 is not compatible with monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0). Package FTD2XX.Net 1.0.14 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)`. From your knowledge, is there a way to make it work?

Comment: that package was last updated in 2014.  .NET Standard was not introduced until 2016

Comment: So you can see no way of integrating it into an Xamarin application @Jason?

Comment: That specific library, no.  If I google "Xamarin FTDI" I get a number of relevent looking hits.  You also linked above to a FTDIWrapper library that may be useful.  Or you can use an Android Binding library like I suggested on your previous question.

Comment: I'll investigate the FTDIWrapper library more, as ideally I would like to make it work on Xamarin rather than just android-specific. Thanks for your help :)